# How to display my Queue & Stack?

Tags: c++, data-structures, stack, queue

I Wanna display my EvenQueue, EvenStack, OddQueue & EvenQueue? I already try some methods but the compiler gave me some errors. 
Any help would be appreciated... Or any tips.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  stack<int> OddStack;
  queue<int> OddQueue;

  stack<int> EvenStack;
  queue<int> EvenQueue;

  int MyNumbers[10];
  int InNum;

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter Number " << i << ": ";
    cin >> InNum;

    MyNumbers[i] = InNum;

    if(InNum % 2 == 0)
    {
        EvenQueue.push(InNum);
        EvenStack.push(InNum);
    }

    else
    {
        OddQueue.push(InNum);
        OddStack.push(InNum);
    }
}

cout << "Stack" << "\t\t" << "Queue" << endl;

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want help with error messages, it's a good idea to tell us what errors you're getting, and on what lines. And if you say "line 13" or something, then show us in the code where line 13 is. Don't expect us to count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign it to tempstack

```
stack<int>tempStack = OddStack
```

and start poping from it and see what is inside

```
while(tempStack.empty() == false){
  int x = tempStack.top();
  cout << x << endl;
  tempStack.pop();
}
```

same goes for the queue